# I have the JS script that makes one div disappear when showing another one. How to add fadein effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/). The script itself is here:

```
$(function () {

    $(".div1, .div2").hide();

    $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {

      $(".div1, .div2").hide();        

      if ($(this).attr("class") == "link1")
      {
        $(".div1").show();
      }
      else 
      { 
        $(".div2").show();
      }
    });

});
```

How can I add smooth fadein effect when one div disappears and the other one shows up? Thanks!

Comment: use `fadeIn()` effect. http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/571/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the `fadeIn()` method from jQuery, as explained in the docs:

> The .fadeIn() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. It is similar to the .fadeTo() method but that method does not unhide the element and can specify the final opacity level.

```
if ($(this).attr("class") == "link1") {
    $( "#div1" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
} else {
    $( "#div2" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
}
```

Instead of `slow` you can also use a number for indicating the fade-in time, in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".div1").fadeIn();
$(".div2").fadeOut();
```

Running example:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".div1, .div2").hide();

    $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {
      var e = $(this);
        $(".div1, .div2").fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          if (e.attr("class") == "link1"){
              $(".div1").fadeIn();
          } else { 
              $(".div2").fadeIn();
          }
        });        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link2">Link 2</a>
    
<div class="div1">I'm div1</div>
<div class="div2">I'm div2</div>
```

The `promise()` is used to avoid the collision between `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` transitions

Answer (score 1):

updated your fiddle.

simply replace `show()` with `fadeIn()`

http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/572/